# Not sending mail with Sendmail and Gmail in XAMPP

Tags: email, xampp, smtp, gmail, sendmail

I'm using XAMPP to a work project. Some months ago I could configure the mail sender with Sendmail using our Gmail account (with corporative domain) and worked very well; however some weeks ago the mail sender don't work and honestly I don't idea what happened if don't change anything.

This is what I have:

**php.ini:**

```
[mail function]
SMTP=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
sendmail_from = mycorporative-id@gmail.com
sendmail_path = "C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe -t"
;mail.force_extra_parameters =
mail.add_x_header=On
;mail.log =
;mail.log = syslog
```

**sendmail.ini:**

```
[sendmail]
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
smtp_ssl=auto
;default_domain=mydomain.com
error_logfile=error.log
debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username=mycorporative-id@gmail.com
auth_password=**********
pop3_server=
pop3_username=
pop3_password=
force_sender=mycorporative-id@gmail.com
force_recipient=
hostname=
```

And in the Apache log error file, I have this errors:

```
[Mon Feb 19 00:02:51.017896 2018] [:error] [pid 4144:tid 1776] [client x.x.x.x:56714] ERROR: mail not sent to  (usermail@anythinghere.com) because of Language string failed to load: tls<p>SMTP server error: K\x0c, referer: .../main/auth/lostPassword.php
[Mon Feb 19 00:02:51.017896 2018] [:error] [pid 4144:tid 1776] [client x.x.x.x:56714] Connection details :: Protocol: smtp :: Host/Port: smtp.gmail.com:587 :: Authent/Open: Authent ::   User/Pass: mycorporative-id@gmail.com:********, referer: .../main/auth/lostPassword.php
```

Do you have any idea what happen here? As I say you, I don't change anything; if you need more info, please ask me. Thank you for you attention and help.